# Cross platform mobile frameworks with native code support

Tags: android, c++, ios, frameworks, native

I'm looking for a list of cross platform framework which have support for building native libraries in C++.  Most of my legacy code base is written in C++, and I'd like to deploy my applications with the native code on the phone instead of using a client/server model.  Wrapping it with networking will introduce latency, reduce performance, and degrade the user experience.

I've looked at some of the basic ones like PhoneGap and Titanium, but I can't from their websites if they support native, or how well they support it.  I've looked at JUCE which is a C++ framaework, but it's not clear how mature it is.

**what i've found so far**

- Juce: open source, small
- Moai: buggy documentation
- Marmalade: stable, mature
- wxWidgets: beta only

**update**

A couple of years later, and it looks like Qt has gotten to the point where it may be the top contender.  Other platforms which have matured in that time include Unity, and Embarcadero.

Comment: PhoneGap works fine and supports native. Not C++ code though. I don't know of any mobile framework which uses C++...

Comment: As noted in the question JUCE does.  I believe Titanium does, but I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Check [MoSync](http://www.mosync.com/), you can build mobile applications with C, C++, HTML5, JavaScript. Check their website to find bunch of technical information.